# Converging Integrals Question

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Im a little confused on how to determine if integrals converge or diverge, Do i take the integral and then the limit to see how it behaves?

Comment: highest power? you've confused the limit of polynomial over polynomial with converging/diverging integral. Perhaps, it'd be a good idea to look at your text book more carefully and see some examples.

Answer (score 2):

(a) The integral is convergent:

$$\frac{7\cos^2 x}{3+x^2}\leq \frac{7}{x^2}$$
and the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$$
is convergent

(b) the integral is divergent:
$$\frac{2}{x\sin x}\sim_0 \frac{2}{x^2}$$
and  the integral 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}$$ is divergent

(c) the integral is divergent:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x^2-2}}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Spot on, Sami! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to give a general algorithm. The argument is usually, but not always,  a "rate of growth" argument, and powers are relevant, though sometimes in a hidden way.

I will systematically use explicit **Comparison** with known integrals, though that is more cumbersome than **Limit Comparison.**

In (a), our integrand is positive, and clearly $\lt \frac{7}{x^2}$. It is standard that $\int_1^\infty \frac{7}{x^2}\,dx$ exists (one need pay no attention to non-zero constant factors).

In (b), the integrand is bad near $x=0$. Indeed it blows up quite fast. Observe that for $x$ in our interval, the integrand is positive and $\ge \frac{2}{x}$. But we know that $\int_1^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{x}$ diverges.

The integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}\sin x}$ would be a little more interesting. For that, the sort of crude estimate we made would not be enough. But we could use the fact that on our interval (excluding $0$) we have $\sin x \lt x$. So our integrand is $\gt \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$, and we know that $\int_1^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\,dx$ diverges.

For (c), note that the integrand is $\gt \frac{2}{2x}$ on our interval.

Comparisons can get subtler. As a small step upwards in complexity, consider 
the following variant of (c), $\int_1^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{4x^2+2000x}}\,dx$. One way to argue is that $2000 x\le 2000x^2$, so our integrand is $\ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{2004}\,x}$, so we have divergence.